# Hello World - EditText and Button don't show up on "Design" screen

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to build my first HelloWorld android app.
I added an `EditText` and a `Button` and it shows up fine when I connect the app to my phone.
But somehow they don't appear in the "Design" screen on Eclipse..
I would like to see them on "Design" screen so that I can put them at the right place.
Does anyone have an idea please?

Comment: Can you see the code in xml page...?

Comment: Post your code.we can`t predict your error without code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yea ...u will have a API version for your design XML on the top...

for API version 20+ , edit text wont be displayed and causes disabling of designView..

[image]so edit that to some 17 or 18 version..it works fine..

or

remove EditText it displays